# Error 1 while buiding by G++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm using eclipse Junior and build my C++ program.
the command line in the console is as following:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/misc/bt_misc.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
```

> g++ -DNDEBUG=1 -DEPOLL=1 -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
>   -I"/home/adtech/workspace/mtracker/src/misc" -I"/home/adtech/workspace/mtracker/src/Tracker" -I"/home/adtech/workspace/mtracker/src/misc/xbt" -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib64/mysql -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/misc/bt_misc.d" -MT"src/misc/bt_misc.d" -o "src/misc/bt_misc.o" "../src/misc/bt_misc.cpp"

I got no error during the compilation phase, unfortunately, encouter an error at the end as following:

```
make: *** [src/Tracker/server.o] Error 1
```

Could you guys help me explain this error. Thanks so much

Comment: Full stack trace, please.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that a command it executed (presumably `g++` when building `server.o`) en­count­er­ed  an error. **Scroll up** and make sure there aren't any errors. The error might not be at the very end if you're running multiple jobs in parallel.